# How to find an IP in overlapping ranges of IPs

Tags: c++, algorithm, ip, time-complexity

I have a large number (millions) of IP ranges which might overlap. An IP range should contain the *start IP*, *stop IP* and an *range id*. How can I efficiently find which ranges contain a given IP?

I could iterate over all the ranges and check for every range if it contains the IP, but I'm looking for a complexity better than O(n).

I'm trying to solve this problem in C++, but I'm open to implementations in any language.

Comment: Which language is this? Have you written any code so far? If so, please edit your post to include it. If this is a general question, try asking on [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: @GoBusto I'm trying to solve this problem in C++

Comment: @GoBusto My code so far includes a naive implementation which has a complexity of O(n) (iterating over all the IP ranges). Not sure if including my code adds any value, but I can do it..

Comment: You could have a look at [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)

Comment: Could you please [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) your question as C++? This will help attract attention from users who know how best to implement solutions in that language.

Comment: @Vincent Thanks! I read a bit about both _interval trees_ and _segment trees_. What are the differences between them? Which one would be more suitable?

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot After doing some research the complexity for querying of a point in an interval tree actually seems to be _O(log n + k)_, where k is the number of outputs. As for the implementations you mentioned, they seem to query for an interval, not a point. Do you think it would still work if I gave as an input an interval of size 1?

Comment: @m.Alin I think for your requirements there is no difference in performance. It seems to me that a segment tree is somewhat easier to implement, but maybe that's just a matter of taste.